# What do you call this word-image made of other words?

Tags: typography, terminology

What do you call this type of image in design term?

[image: Jesus]

Comment: Isn't it just a word-cloud with another word overlaid?

Comment: [Related question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13635/23061)

Answer (score 7):

The closest formal term I know to something like this is a [*calligram*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/88384/77065) which is

> A word or piece of text in which the design and layout of the letters creates a visual image related to the meaning of the words themselves. -- [Oxford definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/calligram)

But most of the time calligrams use the text itself to create the shape of the larger word or image, not just lighting like in the image you provided. Using layout instead of solely text color makes more appealing and less thrown together.

[image]

There are also some similar terms like [word mosaic](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+mosaic&num=20&safe=active&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI5t-ejq_OxwIVC1Y-Ch2nUAOn&biw=2560&bih=1315), [word cloud](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+cloud&num=20&safe=active&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI25Gc-K7OxwIVxKA-Ch30nw5T&biw=2560&bih=1315), [text art (or portraits)](http://www.escapeintolife.com/showcase/art-digital-age-text-portraits/), or [typography art (or portraits)](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/28-excellent-examples-of-typography-portraits/) that are close as well.

Comment: Calligram! What a beautiful word.

Comment: What the OP posted is just a simple mask.

Comment: @Jongware I realize that

Comment: @Jongware It's ok even if it's a mask (I also only noticed after you mentioned it!),  the OP certainly wanted the kind of answer Zach posted but might not have used the best example in his/her question. That is a very nice word indeed, good to know, thanks.