# How to describe this text alignment feature with varied font sizes

Tags: typography, alignment

*Originally posted in the English Stack Exchange, but was suggested to post here.*

I see it all the time in Facebook posters and memes where each row of text is of a different sized font, but with the margins justified. There are even [animations that use this feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QU7usI5HBWo). What is this called?

Sample usage: "How to [*my word*]" as a google query.

---

*Reason for asking: I am sure that there must be an automated way of doing this feature without a compass and slide rule, and that such a feature should be "googleable".*

*(The content in these examples happens to be religious as I randomly took the examples from my Facebook feed. However, I have seen this feature in political memes and animated infomercials.)*

This example has both vertical and horizontally aligned text.

[image]

Comment: It is just type design. I don't think there is a *specific* name for it.

Comment: [Similar technique](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/58833/23061) (and question)

Comment: If you like this design, it's probably a good idea to check typographic grids. They will make you see these designs in a completely new light. Just google the terms, or check  http://www.creativebloq.com/typography/column-grid-poster-design-made-neat-and-easy-10122682

Answer (score 2):

This type of graphic art is generally known as **Typography**. Typography is the art and technique of arranging type to make written language both readable and appealing. However, Typography is a general term as it is used to refer to the structure and consistency of typefaces (fonts).

The type of artwork you are looking at is also generally known as a **Typographic Design** in which words of a phrase or quote are arranged in creative ways by manipulating the size, spacing, thickness, and type of font usually to match the "meaning" of the phrase or quote. Here is an example of a Typographic Design that uses a quote:

https://www.behance.net/gallery/21925843/Quote-Typography-1-Imagination

You can begin searching on Google "Online Typography Maker" or "Online Typography Generator" and find online tools to create such a design. I have found one for you:

http://typographymaker.com/

However, I believe that online tools have very limited features and that you should start getting familiar with actual graphic design software such as Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Illustrator which will help you create much more powerful designs.

Comment: "is known specifically as a Typographic Design"...I'd say just the opposite...it is *generally* known as Typographic Design. It's an incredibly broad term and would encompass much more than this one particular technique.

Answer (score 1):

> This example has both vertical and horizontally aligned text.

That's pretty much it. There's no other specific term for this. It's a style that's been used in various ways throughout history going back to handwritten illuminated manuscripts by the monks. Of more recent history, this was a style popular during the wood-type era where one had access to a wide variety of types to make the forced justification that much easier.